# How to force conda to skip examining conflicts?

Tags: installation, conda, conflicting-libraries

I'm trying to install `conda install -c conda-forge opencv --no-deps --no-update-deps`, but `examining conflicts` takes forever. I found online that this is a known problem without good solutions.

Is it possible to force Conda to skip this step altogether? Probably even simply unpacking the archive with binaries would work for my particular case.

Comment: I am not aware of any option to `conda install` that gets the job done. Have you tried `mamba` or creating a new environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Disable Unsatisfiable Hints

The Conda term for these conflict reports is **unsatisfiable hints**, and there is a configuration option to toggle their reporting:

```bash
$ conda config --describe unsatisfiable_hints
# # unsatisfiable_hints (bool)
# #   A boolean to determine if conda should find conflicting packages in
# #   the case of a failed install.
# # 
# unsatisfiable_hints: true
```

To disable them, set

```bash
conda config --set unsatisfiable_hints false
```